# Storing dates in Oracle in an app used in different time zones

Tags: javascript, oracle, time, timezone

I'm currently trying to decide what to do regarding my web app, which uses Oracle to store data, PHP as server side language and JavaScript as client-side.

The application will be hosted in the UK, but people from UK, US and other European countries will be logging on and using it. At the moment if any 'auditable' event occurs as the result of a user action, a record is saved into the audit trail, with SYSDATE saved against it.

When users then view the audit trail, I want the time to be displayed in their local time zone.

What I am thinking is:
- As SYSDATE is the time of the system clock on the Oracle server, I should make the Oracle server's time zone be set to UTC (with no changes for daylight savings time). This would ensure that all dates are saved in one constant time zone, so converting it shouldn't be difficult.
- Convert the times to local time in the browser using JavaScript's getTimezoneOffset() function to add/subtract minutes.

Is this the right way to do it, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Your approach sounded good right up until this point:

> Convert the times to local time in the browser using JavaScript's getTimezoneOffset() function to add/subtract minutes.

You don't want to do that, as it will yield a different moment in time.  If you are passing a UTC value to the browser, pass it as ISO8601 format and just use that in the constructor, such as `new Date('2013-01-01T01:23:45.678Z')`.

If you need to support older browsers, or you want to have better control over formatting, then consider using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com) instead.

Also, you should be aware that current versions of JavaScript may botch the UTC-to-local time conversion for values near daylight saving time transitions, if the value you're working with is in a period that had a different DST rule than the one currently in effect.  You can read more about this [on my blog here](http://codeofmatt.com/2013/06/07/javascript-date-type-is-horribly-broken/).  You will have this problem with moment or date.

If that is critical to you, then you'll need to avoid doing the conversions in JavaScript, and do it in your PHP code instead.  (Of course, that means you'll need to ask the user for their time zone, such as `America/Los_Angeles`, so you have it available to PHP time zone functions.)

Answer (score 0):

In your tables and PL/SQL code use always datatype `TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIMEZONE`. Then dates and times are always properly inserted and displayed in timezone of current user session.

Datatype "TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE" also contains timezone information, but for proper display you have to convert to user session timezone. When you are in U.S. probably you don't like to see "2012-12-12 15:45:00 -01:00" although it represents correct time.

SYSDATE is data type "DATE" it does not contain any timezone information, use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` or `LOCALTIMESTAMP` for session timestamp or `SYSTIMESTAMP` for timezone where you Oracle server reside.

Comment: Hi, and thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I don't think changing all SYSDATEs to TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIMEZONE is going to be possible for me - this would mean changing literally thousands of SQL statements. Do you think my approach would work though? If all SYSDATEs are stored in UTC, then why does it matter what timezone the user was in when they stored it? It can be converted from UTC to the user's timezone when it is displayed back to them.